# How do I post a character to a console program's STDIN?

Tags: winapi, console-application, stdin

I am writing a Win32 program in C that launches a console application which can be stopped by pressing <kbd>Q</kbd> on the keyboard.  Pressing <kbd>Q</kbd> on the keyboard makes the console application stop; I just want to emulate that with the program I am writing.

I have had no luck with what I think is the standard approach:

- initialize a `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` structure with `bInheritHandle=TRUE`
- call `CreatePipe()` using that structure to initialize read and write handles
- create a `STARTUPINFO` structure with `dwFlags=STARTF_USESTDHANDLES`
- assign `hStdInput` to the read handle initialized by `CreatePipe()`

My program launches the console application with `CreateProcess()` using the initialized `STARTUPINFO` structure, and writes the letter `q` using the `hStdInput` write handle in a call to `WriteFile()`. The console program does not respond.

Should I be sending a scan code instead of a text character?

Comment: Are you writing a lowercase `q` or an uppercase `Q`? Note that writing to a process's `stdin` is not the same thing as simulating a keyboard key press. Maybe the process is monitoring keyboard presses directly and not monitoring `stdin`? We don't know anything about the program you are launching.

Comment: Whether you want to realize a program (A) to start another program (B) and the program A can control the pause of program B with `Q` on the keyboard? Could you please provide a sample to help us better understand what you want?

Comment: Thanks for these useful insights. I will play with WriteConsoleInput, and also posting "q\r". I am afraid I don't know how the spawned program (ffplay.exe, which is a tool the comes with the open source ffmpeg package) reads input. I will update this after I have played a little more with it.

Comment: FFPlay [is not](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/4fb9d946883ba8a3e21a9e756aa27349e6e22cef/fftools/ffplay.c#L3268) a console-mode program, so tinkering with stdin isn't going to get you anywhere.  Emulate keyboard input with [SendInput()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput)

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I just tried SendInput(), and still no luck getting FFPlay to respond to it. The code does work with Notepad -- if I have it open Notepad and call SendInput() the 'q' appears there. I really thought this might work.

Answer (score 0):

If the console program reacts to the **key press** of `q` as opposed to the **input string** with "q", it definitely doesn't process input by reading from stdin. Stdin only sends input to the host application when `Enter` is pressed. The program, most likely, uses `ReadConsoleInput` or something similar.

You could test that - make a text file with q in it, run your console program with `<q.txt`. Chances are, it won't quit.

I don't have an example ready, but `WriteConsoleInput` seems to be the way to go.

Comment: "*Stdin only sends input to the host application when Enter is pressed*" - more accurately, the console/terminal handles that buffering, not stdin itself.

Comment: Point is, if you read from stdin, it blocks until Enter is pressed.

Comment: Again, that behavior is controlled by the console/terminal, not by stdin itself.  It is certainly possible to pipe data into a stdin of a spawned process without requiring Enter be sent. It also depends on how the spawned program is reading from stdin, as it may be expecting an Enter before processing data.

Comment: Poking around the OP's console program with Depends (or ILSpy, if managed) might be illuminating.